# TypeError 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, asyncio

При добавлении int значения выбивает ошибку

**баг**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Максимка\Desktop\JinaPiar\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete       
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\Максимка\Desktop\JinaPiar\main.py", line 17, in main
    users_can_write += users_get[0]['id']
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**main.py**:

```
import vk_api
import asyncio
import time
from random import uniform
from settings import user_token, group_id
from cmds import *

async def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=user_token)
    api = vk_session.get_api()
    users = await get_users(api, group_id=group_id, count=3)
    users_can_write = []
    for user in users:
        users_get = api.users.get(user_ids=user, fields='can_write_private_message')
        if users_get[0]['can_write_private_message'] == 1:
            print(users_get)
            users_can_write += users_get[0]['id']
        else:
            pass

asyncio.run(main())
```

**cmds.py**:

```
async def get_users(api, group_id, count=None):
    users = api.groups.getMembers(group_id=group_id, count=count)
    return users['items']
```

Comment: Распечатайте users_get, что там.  Желательно так print(type(users_get))

Comment: [{'id': 90161, 'can_write_private_message': 1, 'first_name': 'Эльдар', 'last_name': 'Зарипов', 'can_access_closed': True, 'is_closed': False}] - это users_get

Comment: Скрипт и ошибка одна версия? Или ошибку вчера скопировали а скрипт сегодня сто раз переписали, в таком виде у вас не может быть такое исключение!!!

Comment: Скрипт не переписывал, все как в вопросе

Comment: А вообще вру может, вы же одну итерацию показали а у вас их несколько, и вы users_get разные типы попадают. Покажите все итерации если это возможно, и в таких случаях нужно дебажить выше уровнем. Поставьте print(user_get)  после этой строки users_get = api.users.get(user_ids=user, fields='can_write_private_message')

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable эта ошибка вот так получается, a = 0, a[0] <-- 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка вот в чём: `users_can_write` - это массив и к нему вы пытаетесь прибавить число (id пользователя).

Если вы хотите добавить элемент в массив, то нужно воспользоваться методом `.append(...)`

```py
async def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=user_token)
    api = vk_session.get_api()
    users = await get_users(api, group_id=group_id, count=3)
    users_can_write = []
    for user in users:
        users_get = api.users.get(user_ids=user, fields='can_write_private_message')
        if users_get[0]['can_write_private_message'] == 1:
            print(users_get)
            users_can_write.append(users_get[0]['id'])
        else:
            pass
```

Чуть подробнее о методах массива и их возможностях можно прочитать [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html).

Comment: Вообще правильно вы говорите, но разве не должно быть так? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'list' and 'int', что то пайтон в заблуждение вводит.

Comment: Я полностью согласен с вами. Когда первый раз посмотрел на ошибку, я подумал так же, но перепроверил, python 3.10.9 действительно возвращает такую ошибку, указанную в вопросе.